# Trouble with proving uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

prove : $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \dfrac{nx}{e^{nx}}$$
converge for each x $\in R$ , converge uniformly in $[\alpha,\infty)$ for $\alpha >0$ and doesn't converger uniformly at $[0,\infty)$.

Having trouble with that question, 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to say more. What did you try? Surely you tried $x=0, x= 1$?

Comment: HINT:  Does the summand $nxe^{-nx}$ converge uniformly?

Comment: No.  The summand is not the sum.  If the summand fails to UC then the series fails to UC also.  But, I posted a solution that does not rely on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $z/e^z$ has a maximum value at $z=1$ and is decreasing for $z > 1$.

We have for all $n > 1/\alpha$ and $x \geqslant \alpha >0$

$$\frac{nx}{e^{nx}} < \frac{n \alpha}{e^{n \alpha}}.$$

Hence, the series converges uniformly on $[\alpha, \infty)$ by the Weierstrass M-test.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nxe^{-nx}$ fails to be uniformly convergent for $x\in [0,\infty)$.

Take $\epsilon=e^{-1}$.  Then, for $x=1/N$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty nxe^{-nx}- \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} nxe^{-nx}\right|&=\sum_{n=N}^\infty (n/N)e^{-n/N}\\\\
&\ge \sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-n/N}\\\\
&=\frac{e^{-1}}{1-e^{-1/N}}\\\\
&>\frac{1}{e}\\\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align}$$

Therefore, there exists a number $\epsilon =e^{-1}>0$, such that for all $N>1$ there exists a number $x=1/N$, such that $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty nxe^{-nx}- \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} nxe^{-nx}\right|>\epsilon$$

And we are done!

Comment: @Liad The series does UC on $[\alpha, \infty)$ for $\alpha>0$ since $nxe^{-nx}\le n\alpha e^{-n\alpha}$ for $n>1/\alpha$.  The apply the M-test.

Comment: $N>1$ is any number, however large.

Comment: And you're welcome.  My pleasure

Comment: $n$ is a "dummy" summation index that is not fixed, while $x$ is a fixed parameter.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark